# Unable to find symbols when compiling native code for android: ld: error: undefined symbol: free_minutiae

Tags: c, android-ndk, linker-errors

I'm trying to use this https://github.com/amdonov/mintct to compile for use in Android. I have successfully built the .jnilib/.jar file for use on a Mac, but am running into this error (and others, all very similar) when I attempt to do the same for Android:

```
  ld: error: undefined symbol: get_minutiae
  >>> referenced by mindtct.c:38 (/Users/amanda/Repos/NativeLibTest/app/src/main/cpp/mintct-android/mindtct.c:38)
  >>>               CMakeFiles/libmindtct.dir/mintct-android/mindtct.c.o:(extract_xyt)
```

All of the symbols that it cannot find are defined in lfs.h which is contained in ${NBIS_DIR}/exports/include. Opening mindtct.c in Android Studio shows no errors or red squigglies - everything seems to be happy on that end of things.

I have verified that all the missing symbols are defined in lfs.h, tried putting the header directly into the mindtct dir, tried adding different directories/libs - can't figure it out. Overall I have very little experience with compiling C/C++, but I figure it has to be some peculiarity with how Android compiles this stuff, as I had very little difficulty getting it to build for Mac, even with my limited experience.

This is my current CMake file. Not sure if it makes any difference, but it is being called from the boilerplate CMake file (using `include(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/mintct-android/CMakeLists.txt)`)from making an Android project that includes the NDK, as I intend to repeat this process for another library as well.

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.18)
project (mindtct)
set(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE ON)
SET(MINDTCT_DIR ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/mintct-android)
SET(NBIS_DIR ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/NBIS_5.0)
include_directories("${NBIS_DIR}/exports/include"
        "${NBIS_DIR}/mindtct/include"
        "${JAVA_HOME}/include"
        "${JAVA_HOME}/include/darwin"
        "${MINDTCT_DIR}")
link_directories("${NBIS_DIR}/exports/lib")
FIND_PACKAGE(SWIG REQUIRED)
INCLUDE(${SWIG_USE_FILE})
SET(CMAKE_SWIG_FLAGS -package    "com.bah.biometrics")
SWIG_ADD_LIBRARY(libmindtct TYPE SHARED LANGUAGE JAVA SOURCES ./mintct-android/mindtct.i ./mintct-android/mindtct.c)
SWIG_LINK_LIBRARIES(libmindtct mindtct image an2k openjp2 ihead jpegb jpegl
    wsq png fet ioutil util m z)
```

The verbose output I'm getting is:

```
4: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:buildCMakeDebug[x86_64]'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: ninja: Entering directory `/Users/amanda/Repos/NativeLibTest/app/.cxx/Debug/2f6w55m5/x86_64'
  [0/1] Re-running CMake...
  -- Configuring done
  -- Generating done
  -- Build files have been written to: /Users/amanda/Repos/NativeLibTest/app/.cxx/Debug/2f6w55m5/x86_64
  [1/6] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/nativelibtest.dir/nativelibtest.cpp.o
  [2/6] Swig compile ./mintct-android/mindtct.i for java
  [3/6] Linking CXX shared library /Users/amanda/Repos/NativeLibTest/app/build/intermediates/cxx/Debug/2f6w55m5/obj/x86_64/libnativelibtest.so
  [4/6] Building C object CMakeFiles/libmindtct.dir/CMakeFiles/libmindtct.dir/mindtctJAVA_wrap.c.o
  [5/6] Building C object CMakeFiles/libmindtct.dir/mintct-android/mindtct.c.o
  [6/6] Linking C shared library /Users/amanda/Repos/NativeLibTest/app/build/intermediates/cxx/Debug/2f6w55m5/obj/x86_64/liblibmindtct.so
  FAILED: /Users/amanda/Repos/NativeLibTest/app/build/intermediates/cxx/Debug/2f6w55m5/obj/x86_64/liblibmindtct.so 
  : && /Users/amanda/Library/Android/sdk/ndk/23.1.7779620/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/clang --target=x86_64-none-linux-android24 --gcc-toolchain=/Users/amanda/Library/Android/sdk/ndk/23.1.7779620/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64 --sysroot=/Users/amanda/Library/Android/sdk/ndk/23.1.7779620/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/sysroot -fPIC -g -DANDROID -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wformat -Werror=format-security  -fno-limit-debug-info  -static-libstdc++ -Wl,--build-id=sha1 -Wl,--no-rosegment -Wl,--fatal-warnings -Wl,--no-undefined -Qunused-arguments -shared -Wl,-soname,liblibmindtct.so -o /Users/amanda/Repos/NativeLibTest/app/build/intermediates/cxx/Debug/2f6w55m5/obj/x86_64/liblibmindtct.so CMakeFiles/libmindtct.dir/CMakeFiles/libmindtct.dir/mindtctJAVA_wrap.c.o CMakeFiles/libmindtct.dir/mintct-android/mindtct.c.o -L/Users/amanda/Repos/NativeLibTest/app/src/main/cpp/NBIS_5.0/exports/lib -lmindtct  -limage  -lan2k  -lopenjp2  -lihead  -ljpegb  -ljpegl  -lwsq  -lpng  -lfet  -lioutil  -lutil  -lm  -lz  -latomic -lm && :
  ld: error: undefined symbol: read_and_decode_grayscale_image
  >>> referenced by mindtct.c:25 (/Users/amanda/Repos/NativeLibTest/app/src/main/cpp/mintct-android/mindtct.c:25)
  >>>               CMakeFiles/libmindtct.dir/mintct-android/mindtct.c.o:(extract_xyt)
  >>> did you mean: _read_and_decode_grayscale_image
  >>> defined in: /Users/amanda/Repos/NativeLibTest/app/src/main/cpp/NBIS_5.0/exports/lib/libimage.a
  
  ld: error: undefined symbol: lfsparms_V2
  >>> referenced by mindtct.c:38 (/Users/amanda/Repos/NativeLibTest/app/src/main/cpp/mintct-android/mindtct.c:38)
  >>>               CMakeFiles/libmindtct.dir/mintct-android/mindtct.c.o:(extract_xyt)
  >>> did you mean: _lfsparms_V2
  >>> defined in: /Users/amanda/Repos/NativeLibTest/app/src/main/cpp/NBIS_5.0/exports/lib/libmindtct.a
  
  ld: error: undefined symbol: get_minutiae
  >>> referenced by mindtct.c:38 (/Users/amanda/Repos/NativeLibTest/app/src/main/cpp/mintct-android/mindtct.c:38)
  >>>               CMakeFiles/libmindtct.dir/mintct-android/mindtct.c.o:(extract_xyt)
  
  ld: error: undefined symbol: write_minutiae_XYTQ
  >>> referenced by mindtct.c:61 (/Users/amanda/Repos/NativeLibTest/app/src/main/cpp/mintct-android/mindtct.c:61)
  >>>               CMakeFiles/libmindtct.dir/mintct-android/mindtct.c.o:(extract_xyt)
  
  ld: error: undefined symbol: free_minutiae
  >>> referenced by mindtct.c:64 (/Users/amanda/Repos/NativeLibTest/app/src/main/cpp/mintct-android/mindtct.c:64)
  >>>               CMakeFiles/libmindtct.dir/mintct-android/mindtct.c.o:(extract_xyt)
  >>> referenced by mindtct.c:69 (/Users/amanda/Repos/NativeLibTest/app/src/main/cpp/mintct-android/mindtct.c:69)
  >>>               CMakeFiles/libmindtct.dir/mintct-android/mindtct.c.o:(extract_xyt)
  clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
  ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
  
  C++ build system [build] failed while executing:
      /Users/amanda/Library/Android/sdk/cmake/3.18.1/bin/ninja \
        -C \
        /Users/amanda/Repos/NativeLibTest/app/.cxx/Debug/2f6w55m5/x86_64 \
        libmindtct \
        nativelibtest
    from /Users/amanda/Repos/NativeLibTest/app
  CMake Warning at /Users/amanda/Library/Android/sdk/ndk/23.1.7779620/build/cmake/android-legacy.toolchain.cmake:416 (message):
    An old version of CMake is being used that cannot automatically detect
    compiler attributes.  Compiler identification is being bypassed.  Some
    values may be wrong or missing.  Update to CMake 3.19 or newer to use
    CMake's built-in compiler identification.
  Call Stack (most recent call first):
    /Users/amanda/Library/Android/sdk/ndk/23.1.7779620/build/cmake/android.toolchain.cmake:55 (include)
    /Users/amanda/Repos/NativeLibTest/app/.cxx/Debug/2f6w55m5/x86_64/CMakeFiles/3.18.1-g262b901/CMakeSystem.cmake:6 (include)
    CMakeLists.txt:11 (project)
```

Comment: Were you able to solve this issue?

Comment: I would like to know too. I am stuck in a similar situation.